# Does modifying a collective noun with a number make the subject plural?

Tags: american-english, british-english, subjects, collective-nouns

The word *dozen* is a collective noun, i.e., singular when we think of them as groups and plural when we think of the individuals acting within the whole. So we might say:

> Talking about eggs: "A dozen *is* probably not enough."
>   Talking about a party with friends: "A dozen *are* coming over this afternoon."

So, a dozen roses would likely be considered singular (like a bouquet). We might say, "A dozen roses *costs* ten rupees," as per subject-verb agreement.

**1)** However, since we have *six* dozen, does the modification of the noun by a number change the subject to plural, resulting in *cost*? Or is it all moot because of the plural *roses*?

In American English, collective nouns tend to be singular while in British English they may be both. That said, I've seen the suggestion that *cost* be used, which would be straightforward to me if *dozens* (plural) were used. From an American perspective, I feel the subject should remain singular when modified by a number: "Three dozen *is* enough to feed an army," or "Two dozen pizzas *is/are* too much" (the *be* verb is interchangeable in the 2nd example).

**2)** Is sticking with singular in the case above purely my American usage side showing, or is it a shared phenomenon?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plural#Plurals_of_numbers) states:

> When modified by a number, the plural is not inflected, that is, has no -s added.

**3) (Main Question)** Does this have any bearing on whether the subject is treated as a plural? That is, since a plural is not inflected, could the *subject* remain singular, or is this irrelevant?

Note this is [not a duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79709/is-it-correct-to-say-six-dozen-roses-costs-rs-10), since that question is vague and about to be closed and my suggested edit, which is the basis of this question, was rejected.

Comment: I find it unclear what you are asking. -1. Please edit the post; number the questions and replace words like *it* and *this* in them with specific references.

Comment: @jwpat7 Thanks, updated my question and hopefully it's more clear without being long-winded. :)

Comment: Ok, removed my downvote

Comment: There's no absolute rule. From Google Books - ["2 and 2 **is** 4"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%222+and+2+is+4%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):2450 hits, ["2 and 2 **are** 4"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%222+and+2+are+4%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):4,850 hits. Allowing a reasonable "margin of error", it's six of one and half-a-dozen of the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the effective interaction with the *dozens*, I suggest that the singular is appropriate. You are paying one price for the lot. As such *six dozens* is being treated as a single collective unit.

> Six dozen roses costs 60 rupees. *[You are buying one thing]*

If you were quoting a price for each dozen, you probably would say

> Six dozen roses cost 10 rupees per dozen. *[You are buying six things]*

Answer (score 4):

Talking about eggs: "*Three dozen is probably not enough.*"

"*Three dozen eggs is probably not enough*," and "*Three dozen of the eggs is probably not enough.*" also work.

Talking about a party with friends: "*Three dozen are coming over this afternoon.*"

"*Three dozen attendees are coming over this afternoon*," and "*Three dozen of the attendees are coming over this afternoon*" also work.