# Why this sentence use ''is''?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, syntactic-analysis

Eight dollars is the price of a movie these days.

Why dont use ''are''?

Comment: ["Subjects expressing periods of time, amounts of money, or quantities may take either singular or plural verbs depending on whether represent a total amount or a number of individual units. For example, 'Four weeks is not enough vacation time' and 'Two days have passed since I asked for your response.'"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112109/)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, because the phrase "Eight dollars" is considered as price, which is singular.