# "is" vs "are" when followed by a number

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I read the following sentence on YouTube and initially thought it was grammatically incorrect:

> Here are 10 minutes of the movie Black Hawk Down!

I thought "are" should have been "is" but then I realized *minutes* is plural so the plural form, *are*, is used correctly. I also thought how most people would naturally say "Here is ten dollars in change" but is the use of the singular form, *is*, correct since *dollars* is plural?

Am I misunderstanding a rule?

Comment: Celeritas, for what is worth, I think "here is ten dollars in change" is idiomatic English. So, even if it is ungrammatical, it is commonly accepted speeck.

Comment: Here are [several related questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=plural+verbs+with+a+number); you might want to start [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79728) or [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58490).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In most cases, if the subject and verb do not agree then we have a grammatical error, as in the following examples:

> My friend have a dog.
>
> I never eats cheese.

However, there are cases where semantics overrides the usual agreement rules. This often occurs with collective nouns:

> The committee have decided to disband.
>
> The team are not playing very well.

In such cases the speaker conceptualises the committee or team in terms of their members.

The opposite occurs in examples such as:

> Three weeks seems a long time.
>
> Here's ten dollars.
>
> Two eggs is plenty.

According to the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (p504):

> ... here an NP (noun phrase) that is formally plural is conceptualised
>   as referring to a single measure (of time, money, distance, or
>   whatever) and accordingly takes a singular verb. The measure override
>   is characteristically found with *be* or other complex-intransitive verbs such
>   as *seem*.

Comment: This has nothing to do with countable vs uncountable nouns, correct?

Comment: Only indirectly, to the extent that the issue of semantic override in time and money expressions applies only to countable nouns. I can't conceive of a sentence where an uncountable noun is followed by a plural verb: _The money are not enough_. _His luck were bad_. The countability of a noun is most often of significance in deciding which article (if any) to use.

Comment: *Here is ten dollars* is the usual phrase, because it is probably a single banknote. *Here are ten dollars* is what you would say if counting out ten silver dollars (worth a good deal more than $1 each).

Comment: @Tim. Good point. This makes it clear when 10 dollars can be conceptualised as a singular and as a plural entity.

Comment: @TimLymington: I don't know, I think money often gets regrouped as a single object when you're dealing with it as money rather than a set of discrete objects. For example, if I put a pile of coins on the table and asked someone how much, I'd expect them to say "That's seven dollars and 38 cents," rather than "Those *are* seven dollars and 38 cents."

Comment: @aesin; that's my point. Money *is* a mass noun; coins and bills  *are* plural. You could hand over a pile thirty-seven coins high and say either 'Here are thirty-seven cents (including one from Hawaii)' or 'Here's the thirty-seven cents I owe you'.

Comment: @Aesin Also, in your example of "That's seven dollars and 38 cents", "that" is referring to *the pile* (singular) of coins.

Answer (score 3):

> Here is ten minutes of the movie.
>
> Here is two dollars.

The amount, in these examples is taken as a singular value. Here is a ten minute part of the movie.

> Here are the ten minutes of the movie.
>
> Here are the two dollars.

The focus is shifted to the number of minutes, as opposed to a part of the movie.