# When referring to 1 million dollars, do you use it or them?

Tags: grammar

I am not sure because there is more than one dollar, but when referring to the one million dollars only, would you use "it"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["is" vs "are" when followed by a number.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120630/is-vs-are-when-followed-by-a-number) Also [Should we use IS or Are with 'Fifty meters (is, are) the length of this pool.' etc?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268716/should-we-use-is-or-are-with-fifty-meters-is-are-the-length-of-this-pool-e)

Comment: It depends on whether you are referring to the sum as a unit or as multiple units.

Comment: @Lawrence: Nobody says *A million dollars **are** a lot of money.* What possible context might you be thinking of?

Comment: By the same token, you wouldn’t say “He has a million dollar”. So if they are talking about the number of dollars, it’s plural. If they’re talking about the number of ‘million dollars’ or about the whole thing as a sum, it’s singular.

Comment: Look at it this way: Would you say  **10 is a big number** or *are big*?

Comment: @Yosef Baskin Not the best comparison; this could be mention vs use as in '10 is my favourite number'. '10 is a reasonable size for a clutch' works.

Comment: A million dollars were minted last week. And half a million dimes. They will be transported to banks next week.